# What if the travelling salesman travelled by plane?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computer-science, graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman

It seems intuitive to solve a 2D dot-to-dot travelling salesman problem by eye using a greedy strategy. However we can only solve the TSP by eye if the graph is topographically accurate e.g. if A to B is 10 and A to C is 10 then B to C can't be 1000.

Is the greedy strategy still sub-optimal when we obey 2D scaling, ie travelling by plane? Below I managed to create a topographically accurate example where the greedy strategy is indeed sub optimal:

[image]

Starting at S:

- Greedy: `S B C A S` => 2.83 + 4 + 5 + 2.2 => 14.03
- Optimal: `S A B C S` => 2.2 + 3 + 4 + 3.16 => 12.36

Is there something special about the example above that will be common to all suboptimal greedy routes? Can geometry be used to minimize error?

Comment: This is probably a bit too much of a research-level question for [so] - you might want to try [cs.se], although I believe the thing you're looking for is called Euclidean TSP, which is also NP-hard, and has some well-known approximations. You're essentially asking for all special cases which can be solved greedily (since greedy would only be optimal by exception), which is possibly too broad.

Comment: Thanks @Dukeling Euclidean is the term I was lacking! I reposted there anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to expand the comment of @Dukeling into a full answer since it seems to address the questions asked fairly well:

A graph is called a **Euclidean graph** if the vertices of the graph are associated with points in a plane and edges have weights equal to the distance between the points.

Solving TSP on Euclidean graphs is no easier than on general graphs.